# How to draw a square, three-by-three grid of points with a polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create the following diagram with PGF/TikZ?

[image: A three by three square grid of points with a polygonal path drawn between the points]

The diagram consists of a square, 3x3 grid of equally spaced black points, and a blue polygon whose vertices coincide with some of the points of the grid.

Furthermore, how can I specify that the horizontal and vertical distance between each neighboring points should be 1cm, or some other unit of distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy with Ti*k*Z. For the polygon take a look at the first tutorial (p.28 in 3.19a version). For the grid you only need to draw a point and repeat it with a `\foreach` loop (two, to be precise).

In my example the points are separated 1cm (the default distance unit in Ti*k*Z). If you need, say 1.5cm, you could change the scale option: `scale=1.5`.

Something like this:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[% options
   line join=round,
   %scale=1.5
]
% polygon
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,1) |- (1,2) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
% grid
\foreach\i in {0,...,2} \foreach\j in {0,...,2}
  \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Why is the point (2,2) not mentioned? How is it inferred?

Comment: Using the `|-` notation, you connect two nodes by first drawing a vertical and then a horizontal line (or vice versa using `-|`). Therefore using `(2,1) |- (1,2)`, it is not necessary to explicitly state the coordinate `(2,2)` here.