# How to draw a grid of grids-with-polygons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now that I have seen [how to use PGF/TikZ to create a square 3x3 grid of points and draw a polygon between these points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663947/21685), I'd like to create a grid of such grids, like this:

[image: Grid of grids]

How can I produce it using PDF/TikZ? I'd like each polygon to be specified in a relative coordinate system, so that I can easily change the order of the polygons.

Comment: The relative system you're talking about can be obtained by using the `--++` option for the `\draw` command. What have you tried so far? We need more informations to help you.

Comment: @SebGlav: I've tried nothing. I don't know how to approach the problem. I'm not familiar with PGF/TikZ (rather, I used to be a little familiar with it, but it was long ago and I have forgotten everything).

Comment: See my answer to [How to draw a grid of grids-of-polygons without explicitly specifying the positions of the grids-of-polygons?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663962/1952) where the polygons are defined with `pics` and organized into a `matrix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can create a macro for the grid and then use `scope`s to change the coordinate system. Or, if the distance between grids is the same as the distance between points, you can do one bigger grid ant then the `scope`s.

For example, with multiple grids:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% grid
\newcommand{\mygrid}
{
  \foreach\i in {0,...,2} \foreach\j in {0,...,2}
    \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[% options
   line join=round,
   %scale=1.5
]
% first polygon
\begin{scope}
  \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (2,2) |- cycle;
  \mygrid
\end{scope}
% second polygon
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}]  % <-- this changes the coordinate system
  \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) |- cycle;
  \mygrid
\end{scope}
% third polygon
\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]  % <-- this changes the coordinate system
  \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (2,1) |- cycle;
  \mygrid
\end{scope}
% fourth polygon
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3)}] % <-- this changes the coordinate system
  \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (1,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
  \mygrid
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I love an overengineered solution.

This consists of

- A custom TikZ coordinate system (`dot grid cs: <num>`) that takes its argument and converts it into

  ```
  ( mod(<num>-1,<grid width>), int((<num>-1)/<grid height>) )
  ```

  This means, for a 3×3 grid the number 1, …, 9 correspond to the nine dots that are arranged like the numbers on a calculator

  ```
  7 8 9
  4 5 6
  1 2 3
  ```

  or a phone

  ```
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
  ```

  if the *y* axis is inverted.

  For sizes greater than 3×3 these numbers get a little bit uncomfortable but we could adjust the `dot grid cs` so that it interprets `<x>/<y>` as `(<x>, <y>)` usual so that we could also specify the points on the polygon by their *x* and *y* value. (The `/` is preferred over the `,` since the `,` would need to be protected from the `.list` parser.)
- A grid (`dots`) that is setup in a way that the dots are actual line segments of length zero but turned into dots via `line cap=round` (this might be viewer-dependent). The style `grid` determines the output of the grid (the line width will be the diameter of the dots). The `x vec dash` style makes sure that the cheaty dash pattern uses the current *x* vector.

  This can changed by either

  - changing the `grid` style (for a different color) or
  - changing the `diameter` value that is used by the default as the line width.

  If this makes trouble, you can replace the `dots` style with the one that's commented that uses circular nodes.
- The key `do` that actually draws the polygon by using the `dot grid` coordinate system. After the polygon is drawn and closes, `dots` is called that puts the grid on top of the polygon like in the other answers.

I've put all keys in the `polygon dot grid` name space so that it can't conflict with any original TikZ keys. The `polygon dot grid` key is setup so that it can be used use multiple keys in the namespace without having to prefix it everytime.

---

A few more keys, namely `dos`, `dos*`, `Dos` and `Dos*` allow multiple polygons with the syntax `{{poly 1}, {poly 2}, …, {poly n}}`.

The starred version draws closed polygons. The capital `D` indicates the version that also draws the dots but those are always available with the key `dots` anyway. If you want to use open and closes polygons in the same grid you need to use `dos` and `dos*` where the last instance can be a capital version (so that the dots are only drawn once).

---

I've also added `grid poly` as a shortcut to `do*` and a few `grid poly size`s.

And then it's just a matter of

```
\tikz\draw[polygon dot grid={do*={2,4,8,6}, dots}];
\tikz[grid poly size=normal]\draw[red,            grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz[grid poly size=small] \draw[blue,           grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz[grid poly size=tiny]  \draw[green!50!black, grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz \draw[polygon dot grid={do*={4,5,7}, Dos={{1,2},{8,9}}}];
\tikz \draw[green, polygon dot grid/dos*={{1,2,4}, {5,6,8}}]
    {[
      scale=.5,
      polygon dot grid={size=5x5, do={21,12,8,5}}
    ]} [polygon dot grid/dots=red];
```

which would draw

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

---

As always with TikZ/PGFkeys you can set these settings globally or use another macro or style to do some of these things (which I'm using in the `\matrix` with `\tikzGridPoly`).

---

Since you want to draw more than one of these grid, we can use a `\matrix` which allows us to put a separate drawing in a tabular-like alignment.

Since I don't like to repeat myself I setup the cells (→ `polygon dot grid/matrix`) so that they're using `\tikzGridPoly` by default. This means, the content of a cell needs to be a list of points (plural!) on the polygon enclosed in `{}` – or `{\onlyGrid}` as a special case to only draw the grid.

With `execute at empty cell=\tikzGridPoly{\onlyGrid}` we also could make an empty cell have a grid but maybe you actually want insert empty spaces between the grids as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  polygon dot grid/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/polygon dot grid}{#1},
  polygon dot grid={
    x dots/.initial=3, y dots/.initial=3, diameter/.initial=+3pt,
    polygon/.style = blue, % default style for \tikzGridPoly
    dots/.default=,
    grid/.style={
      black, line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/diameter}}},
  polygon dot grid/dimension/.style args={#1x#2}{/tikz/x={#1}, /tikz/y={#2}},
  polygon dot grid/size/.style args={#1x#2}{
      /tikz/polygon dot grid/x dots={#1}, /tikz/polygon dot grid/y dots={#2}},
  polygon dot grid/dots/.style={
    /tikz/insert path={(0,0) edge[x vec dash,
      to path={grid (\tikztotarget)}, polygon dot grid/grid, #1]
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/x dots}-1,%
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/y dots}-1)}},
%  polygon dot grid/dots/.style={/tikz/insert path={foreach[parse=true]\i in {
%       1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/x dots}
%            *\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/y dots}} {
%    node[at=(dot grid cs:\i), polygon dot grid/grid, shape=circle,
%      inner sep=+0pt, draw=none, fill, node contents=,
%      minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/diameter}, #1]}}},
  polygon dot grid/do/.style args={#1,#2}{
    /tikz/insert path={(dot grid cs:#1)},      % start polygon
    /tikz/polygon dot grid/lineto/.list={#2}}, % lines to other points,
  polygon dot grid/do*/.style={
    /tikz/polygon dot grid/do={#1}, % normal polygon
    /tikz/insert path={--cycle}},   % but closed
  %% dos  = multiple        polygons
  %% dos* = multiple closed polygons
  %% Dos  = multiple        polygons with dots on top
  %% Dos* = multiple closed polygons with dots on top
  polygon dot grid/dos/.style ={/tikz/polygon dot grid/do/.list={#1}},
  polygon dot grid/dos*/.style={/tikz/polygon dot grid/do*/.list={#1}},
  polygon dot grid/Dos/.style ={/tikz/polygon dot grid={dos={#1},  dots}},
  polygon dot grid/Dos*/.style={/tikz/polygon dot grid={dos*={#1}, dots}},
  polygon dot grid/lineto/.style={/tikz/insert path={--(dot grid cs:#1)}},
  polygon dot grid/matrix/.style={
    /tikz/execute at begin cell=\tikzGridPoly,
    /utils/exec=\def\onlyGrid{\onlyGrid}%
     \def\tikzGridPoly##1{%
        \ifx\onlyGrid##1\path[polygon dot grid/dots];
        \else\draw[polygon dot grid/polygon, polygon dot grid={do*={##1},dots}];\fi}},
}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{dot grid}{%
  \pgfpointxy{mod(#1-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/x dots})}
             {int((#1-1)/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygon dot grid/y dots}))}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{x vec dash/.style={dash pattern={on 0pt off veclen(\pgf@xx,\pgf@xy)},
                                             line cap=round, ystep=0, xstep=1}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  grid poly/.style={polygon dot grid/do*={#1}, polygon dot grid/dots},
  grid poly size/.is choice,
  grid poly size/normal/.style={
    very thick, polygon dot grid={dimension=1cmx1cm, diameter=+3pt}},
  grid poly size/small/.style={
    thin,       polygon dot grid={dimension=7.5mmx7.5mm, diameter=+2pt}},
  grid poly size/tiny/.style={
    thin,       polygon dot grid={dimension=5mmx5mm, diameter=+1.3333pt}},
}
\begin{document}
\tikz\matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm,
    polygon dot grid={matrix, diameter=1.333pt, dimension=4mm x 4mm}]{
  {1,3,9}       & {1,3,6,8,5}   & {1,3,6,7,5}   & {1,3,6,5,8} & {1,3,6,4}     \\
  {1,3,8,7,5}   & {1,3,8,4,5}   & {1,3,8}                                     \\
  {1,6,9,8,4,5} & {1,6,9,8}     & {1,6,9,8,5,4} & {1,6,9,4}   & {1,6,9,5,8,4} \\
  {1,6,8,7,4,5} & {1,6,8,7,5,4} & {1,6,8,4}     &             & {\onlyGrid}   \\
};

\tikz\draw[polygon dot grid={do*={2,4,8,6}, dots}];
\tikz[grid poly size=normal]\draw[red,            grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz[grid poly size=small] \draw[blue,           grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz[grid poly size=tiny]  \draw[green!50!black, grid poly={2,4,8,6}];
\tikz \draw[polygon dot grid={do*={4,5,7}, Dos={{1,2},{8,9}}}];
\tikz \draw[green, polygon dot grid/dos*={{1,2,4}, {5,6,8}}]
    {[ % This is nasty.
      scale=.5,
      polygon dot grid={size=5x5, do={21,12,8,5}}
    ]} [polygon dot grid/dots=red];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is beautiful! How do I need to change your code, if I want the points of the dotted grids to be numbered from the bottom up, like the pattern on a calculator?

Comment: @EvanAad Replace `y=-4mm` by `y=4mm` (or any positive distance) in the options of the `\matrix` (as I did in the updated answer). I've also moved the defintion of ``\tikzGridPoly` inside of `grid pf polygon grids` so that it isn't defined globally where we don't need it.

Comment: Thanks you. One more thing, please. In addition to the grid of grids I would like, at several points in my document, to embed one of the smaller grids of points. Is there a way to reduce unnecessary repetitions by declaring something in the preamble or in some other part of the document, and then instead of writing `\tikz\draw[every grid dots/.append style={line width=3pt}, blue, grid poly={2,4,8,6}];`, write simply `\tikz\draw[grid poly={2,4,8,6}];`?

Comment: @EvanAad I've changed my answer again to put all keys in their own name space. I hope the examples are clear enough. Besides, you can always use other (shorter) styles do to something, for example `dia/.style={polygon dot grid/diameter={#1}}`. This way, even `grid poly` is just a shortcut to `polygon dot grid/do`. And you can always set the diameter in your preamble and it would be used in your whole document unless you change it.

Comment: Thanks! Why does the polygon color comes out black rather than blue when the polygon is not inside a matrix?

Comment: @EvanAad Because the `polygon dot grid/polygon` style is only used with `\tikzGridPoly` that is only defined inside the `\matrix` – admittedly not a good setup. ☹ You can remove it there and put it inside the `polygon dot grid/do` style for a more consistent solution. (But that will overwrite any color specification before the `do`.) It really depends on your diagrams and how flexible you want to be when it comes to specifying the options of the polygon line.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd like to request another feature, if you have time and interest: the ability to specify more than one polygon in the same 3x3 grid. Actually, I'd delete the line `/tikz/insert path={--cycle}` you used above, so that it would be possible to specify arbitrary polygonal chains, not necessarily closed ones, and then my request becomes: enable the specification of several polygonal chains in the same 3x3 grid. For instance `{1,2;8,9}` would create on the same 3x3 grid a horizontal line segment in the top left of the grid, and another, separate horizontal line segment in the bottom right.

Comment: @EvanAad I've updated my answer yet again. I've opted for the syntax like `{{1,2}, {8,9}}` because that's just a loop of polygons (which are also basically a loop). I've changed the original `do` to not draw a closed polygon anymore. The closed polygons are drawn by the starred versions. Multiply polygons are then specified via the `dos`/`dos*` keys where the capital versions also draw the dots (but you can always specify `dots` manually which I changed so that it accepts now arbitrary options that are forwarded to the internal grid).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: As you've taken this much effort, I hope you make it into a tikz library!

Answer (score 3):

Taking your last qquestion as a reference, here's a way to draw the same polygon but using relative coordinates. Only the first coordinate is absolute (here `(0,0)`):

[image: graph grid polygon]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (1,1) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --++ (0,-1) --++ (-1,-1) -- cycle;
        % grid
        \foreach\i in {0,...,2} \foreach\j in {0,...,2}
            \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is only a partial answer. I'd like to create a grid of grids-of-polygons, and not just one as in your current answer.

Comment: That was meant to let you start. Sometimes, it's better to try by oneself. That's how I learnt Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 3):

I propose to draw each particular polygon inside a `pic`. This way it's easy to build a `matrix` of pics just using their names.

A correct distance for `column sep` and `row sep` helps to get a continous grid.

With the help of `tikz.transformations.mirror` library (from [`tikz-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) package) it's easy to transform the polygons with having to define new ones.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{ext.transformations.mirror}

\newcommand{\grid}{\foreach \i in {0,1,2} \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
            \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);}
            
\tikzset{
    line join=round,
    polygon/.style={thick, blue},
    empty/.pic={
        \grid
    },
   one/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,2)|-cycle;
    },
   two/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   three/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   four/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)-|(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   five/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    },
   six/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   seven/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,1)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   eight/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   nine/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)|-(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   ten/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={3cm,between origins}] {
      \pic{one}; & \pic{two}; & \pic{three}; & \pic{four}; & \pic{empty};\\
      \pic{five}; & \pic{six}; & \pic{seven}; & \pic{eight}; & \pic{nine}; \\
      \pic{ten}; & \pic[xmirror={(1,1)}]{ten}; & 
      \pic[ymirror={(1,1)}]{ten}; &
      \pic[xmirror={(1,1)}, ymirror={(1,1)}]{ten}; &
      \pic[mirror={(0,2)--(2,0)}]{ten}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]