# How to draw a grid of grids-of-polygons without explicitly specifying the positions of the grids-of-polygons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now that I know [how to use PGF/TikZ to create a grid of grids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663955/21685) where every small grid is explicitly positioned in the meta-grid, and the right margin of the meta-grid is rugged, I'd like to know: Is there is a simpler way to do it when the number of items within each row of the meta-grid is fixed and known in advance (say, 7 items per row)?

I'd like to be able to list the grids-of-polygons without specifying their position within the meta-grid, and leave it to PGF/TikZ to place them automatically in such a manner as to first fill the first (top) row of the meta-grid from left to right, then its second row, and so on, as demonstrated in the following figure:

[image: A grid of grids with regular rows of length seven.]

Comment: You can have each polygon-diagram be each its own TikZpicture and let TeX just input linebreaks whenever necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the original answer didn't offer an automatic positioning solution, it was moved to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664073/1952) following OPs suggestion.

This second version, insisits in using `pics` for each particular polygon, but now are placed using a `foreach` loop. This way, we just need to fix the list of pics and the width of desired result.

To simplify the use, a newcommand `\placepics` has been defined. It has a optional parameter which is the number of pics to place on the same row (7 by default) and a mandatory one which is the list of polygons to draw.

It's possible to combine several `placepics` commands into the same `tikzpicture` if we manually compute the correct `shift` for each `scope`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\grid}{\foreach \i in {0,1,2} \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
            \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);}
            
\tikzset{
    line join=round,
    polygon/.style={thick, blue},
    empty/.pic={
        \grid
    },
   one/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,2)|-cycle;
    },
   two/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   three/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   four/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)-|(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   five/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    },
   six/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   seven/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,1)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   eight/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   nine/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)|-(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   ten/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
}

\newcommand{\placepics}[2][7]{
    \foreach \i [count=\ni from 0, 
            evaluate=\ni as \col using {int(mod(\ni,#1))},
            evaluate=\ni as \row using {int(\ni/#1)}] in {#2}{
    \pic at (3*\col,-3*\row) {\i};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\placepics{one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, one, two, empty, four, six, nine, ten}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-9cm]
\placepics[5]{one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, one, two, empty, four, six, nine, ten}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This would be a good answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663955/how-to-draw-a-grid-of-grids-with-polygons) question, and I encourage you to post it there. However, in this question the automation is an essential requirement.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you for the advice, I've used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664073/1952

Comment: @EvanAad I hope that the new version is automatic enough to solve the question.

Comment: @Ignasi Whoops, I must've gotten confused with all these similar questions. :D

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No, you did correct. Your comment was for the previous version of this  answer that I've moved the other question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the code of the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663960/123129) by Juan Castaño to the linked question as a starting point.

#### Adaptations

- defined environment `polygongrid` that sets the position of the scope automatically
- use counters `pgx` and `pgy` for the position
- use `\polygongridsPerLine` to define how many polygons should be in one line
- defined style `polygon` to reduce redundant code

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% grid
\newcommand{\mygrid}{
    \foreach\i in {0,...,2} \foreach\j in {0,...,2}
        \fill (\i,\j) circle (1pt);
}


\newcommand{\polygongridsPerLine}{3}
\newcounter{pgx}
\newcounter{pgy}
\newenvironment{polygongrid}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3*\value{pgx}, -3*\value{pgy})}]
}{
        \mygrid
    \end{scope}
    \stepcounter{pgx}
    \ifnumgreater{\value{pgx}}{\polygongridsPerLine-1}{
        \stepcounter{pgy}
        \setcounter{pgx}{0}
    }{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [% options
       line join=round,
       polygon/.style={thick,blue},
    ]
    % first polygon
    \begin{polygongrid}
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) -- (2,2) |- cycle;
    \end{polygongrid}
    % second polygon
    \begin{polygongrid}
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) |- cycle;
    \end{polygongrid}
    % third polygon
    \begin{polygongrid}
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (2,1) |- cycle;
    \end{polygongrid}
    % fourth polygon
    \begin{polygongrid}
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (1,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
    \end{polygongrid}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very clever. However, I wonder if there's some existing environment that does it, either built into PGF/TikZ, or as an add-on package. Because I may want later to number the rows and columns, or add grid lines to the meta-grid, and it seems like someone must have needed to do this before me, and a ready-made solution might be available.

Comment: As this is a simple problem with a simple solution (shortly expressed within code), I don't think it is necessary to use any package for this (I don't know a built-in solution for this). This way you also have the advantage that everything is easily adpaptable and extendable. So you  could just add that grid and the labels within the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: You answered first, but I accepted [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664034/21685) because it is more flexible: it is easy to change the number of items in a row of the meta-grid; no calculation required on the user's part.

Comment: @EvanAad It is unclear to me what you mean with "it is easy to change the number of items in a row of the meta-grid; no calculation required on the user's part", as this also applies to my answer. There is no need for the user to do calculations, and the number of items per row can be easily changed by setting `\newcommand{\polygongridsPerLine}{3}` or redefining it.

Comment: I may not have understood your code properly. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You can create each picture as `\hbox` and put these `\hbox`es to a paragraph mode (started by `\noindent`). If you set properly `\hsize`, `\spaceskip` and `\baselineskip`, then you have the paragraph with pictures equal to desired grid.

The example below uses the macro `\printpolyg` which creates a single polygon. The numbers in its parameter corresponds to the labels of the possibly edges of the polygons:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The whole example is here. You need not TikZ, only `\pdfliteral` primitive is used. I.e. you can try this by `pdftex` or define `\pdfliteral` for another used engine.

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
\def\cs#1{\csname #1\endcsname}
\sdef{ppol:1}{0 20}  \sdef{ppol:2}{10 20}  \sdef{ppol:3}{20 20}
\sdef{ppol:4}{0 10}  \sdef{ppol:5}{10 10}  \sdef{ppol:6}{20 10}
\sdef{ppol:7}{0 0}   \sdef{ppol:8}{10 0}   \sdef{ppol:9}{20 0}

\def\printpolyg#1{%
   \hbox to20bp{\vbox to20bp{}\pdfliteral{q 1 w \printpolygA#1; Q}\hss}%
}
\def\printpolygA#1{\cs{ppol:#1} m \printpolygB}
\def\printpolygB#1{\ifx;#1h S\else \cs{ppol:#1} l \expandafter\printpolygB\fi}

\bgroup 
   \rightskip=0pt plus1fil
   \spaceskip=10bp \hsize=200bp 
   \baselineskip=30bp 
\noindent
\printpolyg{397}
\printpolyg{26975}
\printpolyg{16975}
\printpolyg{25697}
\printpolyg{4697}
\printpolyg{12975}
\printpolyg{29754}
\printpolyg{297}
\printpolyg{236875}
\printpolyg{253687}
\printpolyg{126875}
\printpolyg{268754}
\printpolyg{2687}
\printpolyg{268745}
\printpolyg{168754}
\printpolyg{168745}
\printpolyg{356874}
\printpolyg{356872}
\printpolyg{256874}
\printpolyg{2387}
\printpolyg{238745}
\printpolyg{387}
\printpolyg{2684}
\par
\egroup
```

The result:

[image: polygons]

Comment: Thanks. This is very clever! Is `\pdfliteral` defined in XeTeX?

Comment: In XeTeX, define `\pdfliteral` as `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}` and in luatex, define it as `\def \pdfliteral {\pdfextension literal}`

Comment: Thanks! How do I need to change your code if, instead of polygons, I wish to draw polygonal chains that are not necessarily closed?

Comment: Remove `h` from the line `\ifx;#1h S\else...`. The `h` is low level PDF operator which does closing the given path.

Comment: It's a beautiful and elegant solution. However, I accepted [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664034/21685) because I really do need the polygons drawn in PGF/TikZ, because I'd like to add some details such as labeling some of the vertices of some of the polygons.

Comment: @EvanAad You can put each picture generated by TikZ into `\hbox` and do `\noindent` followed by `\hbox`es with pictures. The basic is the same, you need only set `\spaceskip`, `\baselineskip`. I created my `\printpolyg` macro only as a bonus in order to show that we need not to use TikZ always.

Comment: Would you please add this option to your answer with explicit code?

Comment: @EvanAad PGF/TikZ uses `\pdfliteral` or an equivalent at the lowest level, too. All PGF/TikZ does is convert the human readable PGF or TikZ language into [the PDF path language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Vector_graphics).