# How to add frames around grids of polygons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to build on the code given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664034/21685), and add frames around the two groupings together with group numbers, roughly like this:

[image: Frames around the groupings]

Additionally, I'd like ideally not to have to specify the `yshift` of the second grouping as done in the above-mentioned post. Instead, it would be nice if the two groupings simply came one after the other naturally, the way letters are naturally rendered one after the other without having to explicitly specify an `xshift` every time.

If it's too complicated to construct a solution based on the above-mentioned post, a second-best alternative would be to construct a solution based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664073/21685), in which the polygons are arranged in a matrix explicitly, rather than implicitly and automatically.

Comment: One very nice way to achieve this is the `fit` library.

Comment: @SebGlav Could you elaborate please?

Comment: What are the conditions to be applied? Is it important that all groups are aligned? Must boxes have the same width? or they adapt to contents? Are the left labels important? Must they be on the left side? ... I think that this question is the fifth on a series which could be simplified knowing what you really want as a final result even if you ask the questions one by one.

Comment: @Ignasi My ultimate goal is to be able to present two groups of polygons in a way that is visually clear and pleasing to the eye, and in a way that makes it easy to talk about the groupings and about the various items in the grouping. It is also important that the groupings be divisions of the same "whole", so they should not be on two separate pages and they should be aligned in a way that is pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that you want to keep all polygons inside the same `tikzpicture` and that you accept to label every group `by hand` and still accept the manual `yshift` for every group.

Under these conditions a possible solution could be to add a name to every `pic`, add a name to some internal coordinates and also add a name to every group of polygons. With all of them it's possible to use `fit` library to easily draw the frames around selected `pics`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\newcommand{\grid}{\foreach \i in {0,1,2} \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
            \fill (\i,\j) coordinate (-\i-\j) circle (1pt);}
            
\tikzset{
    line join=round,
    polygon/.style={thick, blue},
    empty/.pic={
        \grid
    },
   one/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,2)|-cycle;
    },
   two/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   three/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   four/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)-|(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   five/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    },
   six/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   seven/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,1)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   eight/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   nine/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)|-(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   ten/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
}

\newcommand{\placepics}[3][7]{
    \foreach \i [count=\ni from 0, 
            evaluate=\ni as \col using {int(mod(\ni,#1))},
            evaluate=\ni as \row using {int(\ni/#1)}] in {#3}{
    \pic (#2-\i) at (3*\col,-3*\row) {\i};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.75cm,y=.75cm]
\placepics{A}{one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, two, empty, four, six, nine}
\node[fit=(A-one-0-2) (A-seven-2-0|-A-nine-0-0), rounded corners, label=left:I, draw=red] {};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-9*.75cm]
\placepics[5]{B}{one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, two, empty, four, six, nine}
\end{scope}
\node[fit=(B-one-0-2) (B-nine-2-0), rounded corners, label=left:II, draw=red] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to control the labels' font (in particular its size) and distance from the red frames?

Comment: @EvanAad with `\label={[font=..., distance=...]left:I}` you can control distance and text size.

Comment: I feel like the `distance` option is ignored. Are you sure it's `distance`?

Comment: It's `label didtance` https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#autosec-3232

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way for grouping or presenting the polygons. I think it's pleasing to the eye, but it's just my opinion.

In this case, every polýgon is inserted into a `tcolorbox` and all these boxes are automatically organixed inside a `tcbraster`. Each boxed raster encloses one group.

Possible inconvinients for this solution: The groups are visually separated. Internal boxes adapt the width according to the number of columns. All rows contain the same number of polygons.

Possible advantatges: It's still possible to fill them with a `foreach` loop.  Every group can have their aspect. It's possible to apply all customization options provided by `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\newcommand{\grid}{\foreach \i in {0,1,2} \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
            \fill (\i,\j) coordinate (-\i-\j) circle (1pt);}
            
\tikzset{
    line join=round,
    polygon/.style={thick, blue},
    empty/.pic={
        \grid
    },
   one/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,2)|-cycle;
    },
   two/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   three/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   four/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)-|(2,1)-|(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   five/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    },
   six/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   seven/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--(0,1)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   eight/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
   nine/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)|-(1,2)--(1,1)--cycle;
    },
   ten/.pic={
        \grid
        \draw[polygon] (0,0)--(1,0)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=5, raster equal height, tikz upper={x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm}, colback=orange!20]{title=I, fonttitle=\Large\bfseries}
\foreach \i in {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten}{
    \begin{tcolorbox} \pic {\i}; \end{tcolorbox}}
\end{tcboxedraster}

\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=4, raster equal height, tikz upper={x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm}, colback=green!20]{title=II, fonttitle=\Large\bfseries, colback=red!30}
\foreach \i in {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten}{
    \begin{tcolorbox} \pic {\i}; \end{tcolorbox}}
\end{tcboxedraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]